# In my example, do I use quotes around the terms I'm referring to?

Tags: quotes

In economics literature, the IV approach uses what is commonly referred to as the “first stage” and the “reduced form”.

Should I italicize them instead? I'm not sure what to use because I have not written many economics research papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is perfectly acceptable.

The goal is to make clear that you are introducing terms.  Either formatting choice makes it clear to the reader.

See [What is the best way to mention a word: italics, quotes, or single-quotes (apostrophes)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41391/what-is-the-best-way-to-mention-a-word-italics-quotes-or-single-quotes-apost).