# Should I capitalize a word from the middle of a quote if the quote and word occur at the start of the sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, capitalization, quotations

I was writing an essay for a school assignment, when I encountered a quote similar the following:

> Nobody has encountered a black hole, because they're simply too far away to reach.

I then needed to write a sentence like the following:

> "they're simply too far to reach" refers to how black holes are tens of thousands of light-years away at the nearest.

I then wondered if "they're" should be capitalized to say "They're" instead, because it's the first word in that sentence. Should it?

Comment: Also note that the sentences provided are not the actual sentences, just similar ones.

Comment: I would capitalise it because otherwise it will look odd. One way to avoid the problem is to add a few words of introduction before the quote so that the quote is no longer at the start of the sentence. For instance you could say 《_In the quoted passage "they're simply too far away to reach" refers to the fact that black holes are thousands of light years away._》

Comment: Related: [Capitalization in quotations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/535355/capitalization-in-quotations)